# Choosing the right NoSQL Multimodel Database for massive data network

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

We design a fast one-web **document based** JAVASCRIPT node.js application  with a lot of multimodel database processing (documents, keys, graphs, queries, edits, transactions...) and scaling up to huge amount of data.

Now it appears that for example ***MongoDB*** is not built as multimodel.

On the other hand multimodel databases such as ***ArangoDB*** are not optimal for the thousands of nodes and many terabytes of data that will be required.

Would it be wise to migrate from say ***CouchDB*** to a future version of *MongoDB* ?

Would *Cassandra* be the alternative choice as truly scalable database ?

In this context would there be any reason not to use the more flexible ***OrientDB*** ?

How should we go about solving the database paradigm ?

What kind of database software should we implement ?

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 0):

I am using mysql 5.6 to manage multithreaded connecrions to multiple databases across 12x1To ssd and 3x12go raid . Mysql handles i/o across 4 xeon 40 threads for 160 threads × 256  async connections with a 100% load on cpus and 100% load on disk without a glitch. For hours....
Apache + php7 last RC + pthreads .
It is about 20 times faster than node or hhvm.
Could be postgres too !!!
Go classic